# React reset useMemo value

Tags: reactjs

I need to reset the useMemo value in my react app but Im not sure how to do it. I made a minimal example of the setup. Basically when the reset button is click, the `countDetails` value needs to be null.

```
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  const countDetails = React.useMemo(() => {
    if(count === 0) {
      return {
        data: [],
        key: 'index'
      }
    }


    return {
      data: ['hi'],
      key: 'index'
    }
  }, [count]);

  console.log(count, countDetails);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Count</button>
      <button>Reset</button> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the code to [editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kyzitm?file=src%2FApp.js). Im not sure how to do this because when the reset button is click the count variable doenst matter. So the useMemo wont update. This is a minimal example I tried to make. My app is more complex and I cant use a flag of setting the count to 9999 or something then in the useMemo check if count === 9999 then return null. is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
    let countArr = React.useMemo(() => {
    if (count === 0) {
      return {
        data: [],
        key: "index",
      };
    }

   return {
      data: ["hi"],
      key: "index",
    };
  }, [count]);

  console.log(count, countArr);
  const resetHandler = () => {
    countArr = null;
    console.log(countArr);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello StackBltz!</h1>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Count</button>
      <button onClick={resetHandler}>Reset </button>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: This doesnt trigger a re render of countArr. And its bad react practice to set it like countArr = null

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={() => setCount(0)}>Reset</button>
```

Your `useMemo` is directly dependent on the `count` coming from `useState`. I hope I understand you correctly that in your case, *resetting* means going back to zero. If that is the case, the code above does exactly that, it resets the count back to zero.

Comment: need to reset countDetails variable, not the count state

Comment: that doesn't make sense, `countDetails` are derived from `count`

Answer (score 0):

Set the count to 0

```
<div>
  <h1>Hello StackBltz!</h1>
  <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
  <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Count</button>
  <button onClick={() => setCount(0)}>Reset </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to reset countDetails not the count state variable

Comment: But your countDetails will only give a new return value when the count value changes, cuz it's in your useMemo dependence array.